# How can I fix this pip error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, environment, archlinux

I am having some trouble understanding and fixing this issue in my python installation. Hopefully someone can help me wrap my head around this..?

Python itself runs (ie: the `python` command produces the expected REPL). When I try to use pip (pip search, pip install, ...) I get the following traceback (apparently there are core modules missing..?!):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 13, in <module>
    import shutil
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 13, in <module>
    import tarfile
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 48, in <module>
    import struct
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/struct.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _struct import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_struct'
```

But how can that be?

I've tried reinstalling python (through pacman) to no avail. Ditto for python-pip.

Perhaps the exception is misleading..?

What's with the core module `struct` importing a private version of itself that *doesn't exist*?! How could such an omission exist? Everyone's python 3.6 would be broken.. no?

```
sys.path = ['', '/code/scott/Py/Path', '/usr/lib/python3.6/Tools/scripts', '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload']
```

Python version:

> Python 3.6.0 (default, Jan 16 2017, 12:12:55)  [GCC 6.3.1 20170109] on
>   linux

Pip version: `9.0.1-2` (Built: 24/12/2016 06:47:25)

OS: Manjaro Linux (Arch Linux + KDE)
Kernel version: `4.9.9-1-MANJARO` (from KInfocentre)

python and pip (python-pip) installed through `pacman` (arch package manager) via the commands:

`sudo pacman -S python`

`sudo pacman -S python-pip`

Ah! Importing struct from inside python produces the same error:

```
import struct
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/struct.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _struct import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_struct'
```

...What information would be helpful? I can add to my question..

Comment: What is your `sys.path`?

Comment: Thanks! I've added that information to my question.

Comment: Information that would be useful: Python version and `pip` version, how exactly you installed *both* of them. Your OS version. Showing us if you can `import struct` when you open a python REPL. By the way: a lot of modules import a private version of themselves. Usually the private version is written in C for speed.

Comment: Thanks! I'm adding that information now

Comment: @Bakuriu I've finished adding the information you requested. Thanks! Also, regarding the import _struct, the part that gets me is: how can it be missing? These are core modules so surely such an error could not exist...

Comment: `_struct` is a built-in module. It is "compiled in" Python and there is no file to look for. The command `python -c "import sys ; print('_struct' in sys.builtin_module_names)"` should return `True`. If not, there is a problem with the Python executable or the Python runtime library.

Comment: On Arch Linux (not manjaro) the `sys.path` looks like this: `['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages']`